# How do I pass the first argument of a Vlookup using a variable in a called Sub in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel-formula, vlookup

I can't get Vlookup to use the value of a variable as the first argument.
My main sub uses Call DepthReplace(16). Variable depth has a value of 16 after the call.
The Sub DepthReplace works if I hardcode 16 into the Vlookup.
I've tried various syntax (including single quotes before and after depth), and either get an error or the word "depth" inserted in the formula

```
Sub DepthReplace(depth As Single)
 Sheets(FARD).Select
 ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(LastRowFARD, 30)).AutoFilter Field:=30, Criteria1:=depth
    With Sheets(FARD).AutoFilter.Range
       TestExists = Range("AD" & .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)(1).Row).Value
    End With
    If TestExists <> "" Then
        Range(Cells(4, 4), Cells(LastRowFARD, 4)).Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "=(VLOOKUP(""" & depth & """,'Shelf-WD SKUs'!R4C2:R13C9,2,FALSE)"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the `(` before `VLOOKUP`, and use `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Value`.

Comment: Why the extra quotes before and after, if you're looking up a number? Why use `.Value` instead of `.FormulaR1C1`?

Comment: @GSerg  Worked perfectly using `.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(" & Depth & ",'Shelf-WD SKUs'!R4C2:R13C9,2,FALSE)" `

Comment: @BigBen, I'm relatively new to VBA, but have programmed in the past.  When is it appropriate to use .Value?  Only if putting a constant in cells rather than a formula?

Comment: That is my rule of thumb. `.Formula`, `.FormulaR1C1`, `.FormulaLocal`, etc. for formulas.